# Does MySQL (5.6) always cache the entire result set for a query in memory/on disk?

Tags: mysql, database

I need to dump a few very large MySQL tables to csv (hosted on RDS so no SELECT INTO OUTFILE). These tables are far larger than the available memory on their server.

If I execute a `SELECT * FROM a_big_table` using a python framework with `fetchmany()` or `fetchone()` to grab the records, will `MySQL 5.6` try to read the entire table into memory first (which I expect will result in caching to disk), or is it smarter than that?

EDIT: To clarify, I mean will the whole result set be stored in MySQL cache (not Python!).

2nd EDIT: Changed typo “sorted” to “stored” in first edit. Comments still useful regarding this case tho!

Comment: In response to the edit: It will be materialized and sorted by MySQL _if_ you have ORDER BY (and there are no indexes that can be used to fetch presorted data).

Comment: Thanks Brando, good to know

Answer (score 3):

The used amount of memory used on the server is defined by buffer pool size configuration setting. There's hardly any need to worry about what's happening on the server side. Your fetching application will probably be the bottleneck and thus be able to write the dump slower than MySQL can output. Server just takes care of filling the buffer while you fetch. Fetching one larger result set from server's standpoint is more efficient and less resource demanding than making multiple smaller range queries...

Comment: +1 for: _"Fetching one larger result set from server's standpoint is more efficient and less resource demanding than making multiple smaller range queries"_. In other words, doing things in a set-oriented way will tend to be faster (sometimes by orders of magnitude) than RBAR (Row By Agonizing Row).

Answer (score 2):

Typically in app level database calls, the entire result set is not returned, but rather a cursor into the result set is returned.  It is then up to the app language (e.g. Python) to iterate that result set and retrieve the records.

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connectargs.html) for MySQL's Python connector confirms this:

> **By default, MySQL Connector/Python does not buffer or prefetch results. This means that after a query is executed, your program is responsible for fetching the data** (emphasis mine). This avoids excessive memory use when queries return large result sets. If you know that the result set is small enough to handle all at once, you can fetch the results immediately by setting buffered to True. It is also possible to set this per cursor (see Section 10.2.6, “MySQLConnection.cursor() Method”).
>
> Results generated by queries normally are not read until the client program fetches them. To automatically consume and discard result sets, set the consume_results option to True. The result is that all results are read, which for large result sets can be slow. (In this case, it might be preferable to close and reopen the connection.)

So, your strategy of using a `SELECT *` query, then writing to file one record at a time, or groups of records at a time, should work from a memory requirements point of view.  Your Python code should only need as much memory to hold the current record(s) you are trying to write to file.

Comment: This is all true, but doesn't MySQL have to hold the result set somewhere before the results are given to the app? So a `SELECT *` will always store the result set once somewhere.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Not sure what you are asking here.  If his RDS instance cannot even tolerate running a basic select query, then _nothing_ in RDS is going to work.  If it _can_ support it, then there is no reason why his Python code cannot obtain a cursor to iterate a result set.

Comment: I agree, it should be able to cope. The basic idea behind my question was that MySQL has to execute queries in sequence. So after the `SELECT *` there might be a `DELETE` of a selected record, but you still want that data to be present in your previous `SELECT *`. This means MySQL has to store the whole `SELECT *`. In the unlikely case that this give you problems you could concider limiting the `SELECT *` and read the data in chunks.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I think you are missing the whole point of this question.  The point of the question is that the OP is afraid that `SELECT *` will pull the _entire_ result set into Python memory, thereby crashing the application.  The answer is that no, by default, this is not how Python's MySQL connector works.

Comment: Yes, that's true.

Comment: Hey Tim, thanks for the reply, but it doesn’t quite answer my question. I was specifically wondering if it gets cached on the MySQL server (I understand you can avoid caching in the Python process by iterating over a fetchone/fetchmany cursor)

Comment: @Jinglesting I'm surprised you would even be asking about that.  You're really just asking if your RDS instance can support querying the tables it is hosting.  My guess would be yes, it can.  Do you have some reason to suspect that it would not?  My answer is still relevant, I think, because it shows that the result set is only served out when Python asks for it.  Yes, there may be a cache (e.g. MemCached), but that would only exist to speed up the query.

Comment: Thanks @TimBiegeleisen. I'm only concerned that the process will be significantly slowed down by the fact that the MySQL server will attempt to cache the result set on disk. If this would be the case, I am considering iterating through the table using the primary key and where conditions. I'm just trying to learn whether that is likely to be the case.

Comment: @Jinglesting Most DBMSes do *not* materialize the entire resultset in memory (when possible - e.g. when there are no big sort operations in the plan). Instead, they execute the plan operators as the client fetches rows. I can confirm Oracle and MS SQL Server work that way and I'd be surprised MySQL doesn't. Now, there are things like buffer and result caches, but these are orthogonal to the aforementioned mechanism and are automatically managed by the DBMS (i.e. you don't have to worry they'll grow out of control and crash the server).

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic Well I consider a cache on top of the database as more of an optimization thing, e.g. for records/keys which are frequently being queried.  No one is going to setup a cache which can grow so large that it will take down the entire SQL database.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Hence I wrote: _"you don't have to worry they'll grow out of control and crash the server"_ :)

Comment: MySQL tends to generate the result as the client accepts it, suspending page reads when  the server is blocking, waiting on the client... but yes, there are ways in which poorly-written queries can take down an entire database by exhausting it of disk space -- the most obvious being a query that can only be rendered by materializing a large temporary table.  It's not technically a cache but the potential problem exists.  And of course you can cause this deliberately with [`SELECT SQL_BUFFER_RESULT ...`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html).